# Maintaining Constant Input Voltage (DC) and Limiting Power Drawn from a Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage, watts

I am utilising a power supply capable of providing up to 24 VDC and 3A for a project, however, I am unsure of how to fix the source voltage at 24V nor limit the power drawn by my project to 10 Watts.

As you can probably tell I am a complete novice. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: how much current does your project draw at 24v? If it draws less than 3A, result happiness. If it draws more than 3A, result misery. Where did this spare 10W figure come from?

Comment: Sorry, a more suitable question would be how would I fix the power supply's source voltage at 24V if it is capable of providing 24VDC and 3A to my project. The project does not draw anything greater than 1.8A.

Comment: Normally he current of the load is determined by the resistance of your project.  If your project will only draw 1.8 A the 24 V 3 A supply will work.

Comment: 24V * 1.8A = 43.2W.  As Neil_UK says "Where did this spare 10W figure come from?"

Answer (score 2):

If the power supply is a conventional one with a regulated output then there should be a 24VDC output with loads ranging from zero all the way up to 3A. There may be some variation within the specifications for such regulated unit such as for example 24VDC +/- 5%.

There are some types of regulated power supplies that may require a minimum load in order to maintain the regulated output at 24V. Usually this minimum load requirement would be specified in the power supply data sheet. For example it may be specified as a percent of full load (FL). In such case if specified as 10% of FL then you would have to arrange the load to be at least 0.3A to see the 24VDC output within voltage range.

There are also power supplies that have unregulated outputs. On these the output voltage will vary based upon how much load current the power supply will provide. Generally it is the case that at lower load current the output voltage will be higher and as load current increases the output voltage would decrease. The relationship between voltage and load current may not necessarily be linear. If you have this type of power supply and yet your load requires a fixed 24VDC then you have two things to consider. (1) Replace your power supply with the regulated output type as described above. Or (2) add a voltage regulator between the supply and your load. This latter solution does require that the supply output be a high enough voltage so that the regulator operates within its specification to produce the needed 24VDC output at the required load current. The unregulated supply minimum input voltage to the 24VDC output voltage difference needed will depend upon the type of voltage regulator used (linear or switching) but may need to be 3 to 4 volts.

Finally let us consider the subject of how much current the power supply gives to your load. If the load requires a certain amount of current at 24VDC then the load will draw that much current. It will not be forced to take any more. It is a common misconception for people new to electronics to think that a load has to swallow up the full rated capacity of the power supply but this is not the case.